# What is a term for a problem that is hard to approximate within a factor $c$?

Tags: approximation, complexity-classes

Let $f$ be a maximization problem. If there is a reduction from SAT to the following problem: "given an integer $c$, decide if there is an $x$ for which $f(x)\geq c$", then $f$ is NP-hard. Suppose there is a reduction from SAT to the following problem:

> Given an integer $c$, return "yes" if there is an $x$ for which $f(x)\geq 3 c$, and return "no" if there is no $x$ for which $f(x)\geq c$ (otherwise, the reply is undefined).

This means that, unless P=NP, there is no 3-factor approximation to $f$. What complexity class does $f$ belong to?

Initially, I thought it must be APX-hard, since it is hard to approximate. But
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX#APX-hardness_and_APX-completeness) defines a problem as APX-hard as: "there is a PTAS reduction from every problem in APX to that problem", and I am not sure it is equivalent.